# asp.net core Angular2 MVC http get issue

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, http-get

i am new to Angular 2. i am trying to get data from MVC controller from angular 2

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'subscriber',
    templateUrl: './subscriber.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./subscriber.component.css']    
})
export class SubscriberComponent {

    public IVM: IncidentViewModel;


    constructor(private http: Http) {
        //this.IVM.ID = "ID";
        this.http.get('api/Form/IncidentForm').subscribe(res => this.IVM = res.json() as IncidentViewModel); //map
        console.log(this.IVM.ID)
    }


}

interface IncidentViewModel {
    ID: string;
    Code: string;
    DateTime: Date;
    Address: Address;
    Contact: ContactViewModel;

}

interface ContactViewModel {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Telephone1: string;
    Telephone2: string;
}

interface Address {
    street1: string;
}
```

this is my controller

```
namespace Subscriber.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class FormController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public  IncidentViewModel IncidentForm()
        {
            List<TimeLineViewModel> TLVM = new List<TimeLineViewModel>();
            TLVM.Add(new TimeLineViewModel()
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Notes = "notes 1",
                Title = "n1"
            });
            TLVM.Add(new TimeLineViewModel()
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                Notes = "notes 2",
                Title = "n2"
            });
            TLVM.Add(new TimeLineViewModel()
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
                Notes = "notes 3",
                Title = "n3"
            });
            TLVM.Add(new TimeLineViewModel()
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                Notes = "notes 4",
                Title = "n4"
            });

            IncidentViewModel IVM = new IncidentViewModel()
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Code = "12345678",
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Contact = new ContactViewModel()
                {
                    FirstName = "kostas",
                    LastName = "kostas",
                    Telephone1 = "6974123456",
                    Telephone2 = "2101234567"
                },
                Address = new AddressViewModel()
                {
                    Street1 = "asdf 9"
                },
                TimeLine = TLVM
            };
            return IVM;
        }
    }
}
```

i cant bind data from controller to angular2 component. when i try just to display inside console (console.log(this.IVM.ID)) i get an error unidentified so i think that the issue is inside subscribe. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The get should look more like this:

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

See the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data) for a complete example.